# How to assign computed values to enum using typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, enums

I wanted assign values to enum type. note :text and text1 are actually coming from different file.

```
const text = "sample text";
const text1 = "Sample text";

const enum textDisplay{
  text = text;
  text1 = text1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's not how enum work, you can't assign dynamic values to enum, computed values are not permitted in an enum with string valued members.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html

> The enum member is initialized with a constant enum expression. A constant enum expression is a subset of TypeScript expressions that can be fully evaluated at compile time. An expression is a constant enum expression if it is:

- a literal enum expression (basically a string literal or a numeric literal)
- a reference to previously defined constant enum member (which can originate from a different enum)
- a parenthesized constant enum expression
- one of the +, -, ~ unary operators applied to constant enum expression
  +, -, *, /, %, <<, >>, >>>, &, |, ^ binary operators with constant enum expressions as operands